# ASP.NET MVC - Label não exibe por causa de caracter "ponto" no final do parâmetro name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tive um problema onde um label não aparecia na página que eu estava criando com Razor.

Descobri que o problema era porque o parâmetro "string name" estava com um ponto no final. Gostaria de saber se isso é um bug do ASP.NET ou se tem alguma explicação lógica para esse problema.

Meu código com erro é o seguinte:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Codigo Aut.", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.TextBox("pesquisaCodigoAutorizacao", null, new { @class = "form-control input-md" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Quando eu retiro o ponto do "Aut." que eu tinha usado para abreviar a palavra "Autorização", então o label passa a ser exibido normalmente.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Codigo Aut", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.TextBox("pesquisaCodigoAutorizacao", null, new { @class = "form-control input-md" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O [Html.Label](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee310185%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) [existe sobrecargas](http://LabelExtensions.Label%20Method) e a qual você precisa usar no seu código é o ***seguinte***:

```
@Html.Label("CA", "Codigo Aut.", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
```

onde está o texto ***CA*** é `for` do atributo [html](/questions/tagged/html) do `<label>` e ***Codigo Aut.*** a descrição do seu `<label>`, e a saída desse código:

```
<label class="control-label col-md-1" for="CA">Codigo Aut.</label>
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Html.Label](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee310185%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [LabelExtensions.Label Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.label(v=vs.118).aspx)
- [Using Html.Label html helper](https://forums.asp.net/t/1993021.aspx?Using%20Html%20Label%20html%20helper)